# Cannot convert an int number into array (in C) to output next 10 octal numbers

Tags: c, arrays

I need to input a 4-digit octal number to output the next 10 octal numbers. I do not get any errors but my program cannot convert the inputted number into an array (as required) so it naturally can't output the next 10 octal numbers too.
My source code is the following:

```
int main()
{
    int octNum[4];
    int num;
    printf("Enter the digits of 4-digit octal number to print next 10 octal 
    numbers:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    int i = 3;
    //convert number to array
    do {
        octNum[i] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        i--;
    } while (num != 0);

    printf("\nThe number is %i%i%i%i", octNum[0], octNum[1], octNum[2], 
    octNum[3]);

    //getting next 10 octals
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        octNum[3]++;
        for (int j = 3; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (octNum[3] == 8)
            {
                octNum[j-1]++;
                octNum[j] = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%i\t", &octNum[x]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show sample input you are using and the sample output you are getting. Also, double check why you are dividing by 10 if you are performing an octal conversion?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin a possible input is: 1234, the output I get is: The number is 123415728340
15728344
15728348
15728352
15728356
15728360
15728364
15728368
15728372
15728376
Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: You may not have gotten any errors, but there is a warning which you definitely need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the below code which uses standard c library functions to achieve the same result :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        int res=0;
        printf("Enter octal number");
        scanf("%4o",&res);//Converts the input in octal format to integer and store in res
        int i;

        printf("%4o\n",res);//Print res in octal format 
        char nextNum[10];
        for(i=0;i<10;++i)
        {
                sprintf(nextNum,"%4o",++res);//Store octal value of res in a string 
                printf("%s\n",nextNum);//Print the octal value 
        }
        return 0;
}
```

You can use `printf`'s format specifier `%o` to achieve your results.
Please do have a look at [Printf Format Specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

you can also have a look at `sprintf` and `sscanf` if you are interested .

If you want to store your results in an array use sprintf to convert the given number to octal format and store it in an array by using the resultant string.

I have used library functions for the conversions since it is already available and well tested. Be aware that it does not perform any error checking , the numbers have to be in the specified format or you might get unexpected results.

Here is a sample output:

```
Enter octal number4566
4566
4567
4570
4571
4572
4573
4574
4575
4576
4577
4600
```

Comment: Sreedev Shibu This works great, but the assignment asks me to use an array called int octNum[4] specifically with octNum[0] representing and leftmost octal digit and octNum[3] the least significant octal digit.

Comment: I have added another answer correcting your code. Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Your corrected code is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int octNum[4];
    int num;
    printf("Enter the digits of 4-digit octal number to print next 10 octal    numbers:\n");
    scanf("%i", &num);

    int i = 3;
    //convert number to array
    do {
        octNum[i] = num % 10;
        num /= 10;
        i--;
    } while (num != 0);

    printf("\nThe number is %i%i%i%i\n", octNum[0], octNum[1], octNum[2],    octNum[3]);

    //getting next 10 octals
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        octNum[3]++;
        for (int j = 3; j > 0; j--)
        {
            if (octNum[j] == 8)
            {
                octNum[j-1]++;
                octNum[j] = 0;
            }
            else//add this else statement
                break;
        }
        for(i=0;i<=3;++i)//Printing has to be done in a loop
                printf("%d\t", octNum[i]);//You were printing address of octNum[i] rather than octNum[i]
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Enter the digits of 4-digit octal number to print next 10 octal    numbers:
1234

The number is 1234
1   2   3   5   
1   2   3   6   
1   2   3   7   
1   2   4   0   
1   2   4   1   
1   2   4   2   
1   2   4   3   
1   2   4   4   
1   2   4   5   
1   2   4   6
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better not to use `%i` format specifier here because it will accept inputs in binary and octal (and hexadecimal).

For example, if you input `14`, it will place the number `14` (in decimal) in `num`. 
And if the input is `014`, it will place the number `12`, which is the decimal equivalent of the octal number `14`, in `num`.

---

After getting the digits of the input number in `octNum[]` with the most significant digit in `octNum[0]` and the least significant digit in `octNum[3]` as you have done, you could do

```
int c[5];
for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
{
    //Resetting the carry values
    c[0]=c[1]=c[2]=c[3]=0;
    c[4]=1;

    for(int j=3; j>=0; --j)
    {
        c[j] = (octNum[j] + c[j+1])/8;
        octNum[j] = (octNum[j] + c[j+1])%8;
    }
    printf("\n%d%d%d%d", octNum[0], octNum[1], octNum[2], octNum[3]);
}
```

The array `c[]` is used to store the carry values. `c[4]` is made `1` to increment the number each time.

Sample output:

```
Enter the digits of 4-digit octal number to print next 10 octal numbers:
4577

4600
4601
4602
4603
4604
4605
4606
4607
4610
4611
```